# CScrollView Offset Client Rect with Scroll Position

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, scroll

I am trying to write a function that will work out if the window that currently has focus is entirely shown in the client rect of my `CScrollView` but I am struggling to work out what I am doing wrong. This is what I have thus far:

```
CWnd * pWnd = pView->GetFocus();
if(pWnd)
{                               
    CRect winRect;
    pWnd->GetWindowRect(&winRect);
    pView->ScreenToClient(&winRect);    //pView is a pointer the CScrollView        

    CRect viewRect;
    pView->GetClientRect(&viewRect);

    CPoint currentScrollPoint = pView->GetScrollPosition();
    viewRect.OffsetRect(currentScrollPoint);

    if(!(viewRect.PtInRect(winRect.BottomRight()) && viewRect.PtInRect(winRect.TopLeft())))
    {
        //Not shown fully
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here or suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: if you are using window/viewport for your scrolling, you could try getting the client DC `CClientDC dc(this);` and comparing the window/viewport origin and extents (the window origin/extent is returned in logical coordinates, those of the viewport are returned in device coordinates)

Comment: What happens when you run this in a debugger? Are the co-ordinates as you'd expect?

Comment: @EdwardClements I can create a `CClientDC` but I am not sure what you are suggesting that I do with it. Could you explain further?

Comment: @snowdude here are some values:
`winRect: top = 174, bottom = 198, left = 0, right = 402`
`viewRect: top 0, bottom 168, left = 0, right = 402` `currentScrollPoint: x = 0, y = 174`
`viewRectWithOffset: top = 174, bottom 342, left = 0, right = 402`

This means that the `wndRect` is within the calculated Rect which isn't the case so there is obviously something wrong in my calculation.

Comment: this is only if you are using window/viewport for your scrolling -- my idea with `CClientDC dc(this);` is,
a) if dc.GetViewportOrg() is not 0,0 then your client window is scrolled, so the whole window is not displayed in the view
b) compare the sizes of `dc.GetViewportExt()` converted to logical units and `dc.GetWindowExt()`, if they are different, the whole window is not displayed in the view

Comment: @EdwardClements This is the first time that I have ever heard of viewports so I am guessing that I am not using them. My app is a simple MFC SDI with `CFormView`, which looks after the scrolling. I have multiple dynamically generated `CEdits` on the View and when I tab to one that is not shown by the current client rect I want to scroll to display that `CEdit` which is why I need to be able to work out if the window which has focus is fully displayed in the current client rect or not.

Comment: Is it a little bit out or a lot out?

Comment: It looks like I have fixed my problem. It turns out that offsetting the client rect with the scroll position was the problem, by taking that out the calculation seems to be working. My next problem is that I want to `ScrollToPosition` to the top of the window but using `pView->ScrollToPosition(CPoint(0, winRect.top))` doesn't work. Any ideas there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments to the question above cleared up  the actual intent of the question:

```
...when I tab to one that is not shown by the current client rect I want to scroll
to display that `CEdit`...
```

I found two articles searching MSDN for `CFormView scroll tab key`:

- the [first one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155918) uses  `OnCtlColor()` to check if a sub-window has the focus and is not in view; it uses `ScrollToPosition()`
- the [second one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219282) mentions that `ScrollToPosition()` does not work in Windows CE (both the articles are quite old!), checks for `WM_KEYUP` of the tab key in `PreTranslateMessage()` and uses it's own `ScrollToPos()` function to scroll the control into view (this article was meant for Windows CE and you will need to replace `wce_GetNextWindow` by `GetNextWindow`